# Echo only valid user

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Bash newbie question: I'd like to have this script echo out only users from a given list that are valid user IDs, and not echo the invalid ones.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
    do
        id "$line"

        if [ $? -eq 1 ] ; then

        echo $line

        else

        echo "$line is not valid user ID" >&2
fi
    done < "$1"
```

Instead, it is echoing out the results of 'id' as well as the text "is not valid user ID"

```
uid=17931(wwirls) gid=100000(all_usr) groups=100000(all_usr),12(everyone),62(netaccounts),701(1)
wwirls is not valid CruzID
id: smak: no such user
smak
```

Ideally, it'd echo results like:

```
wwirls
otheruserid
admin
```

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id "$line" &> /dev/null
```

is probably the smallest change that will do what you want.  That says to send the output of `id` (including any error messages) to the bit bucket (`/dev/null`).  However, the sense of your test is backwards - `$?` is `0` on success, and `1` on failure.

Now, as it happens, `if` automatically looks at `$?`.  So you can shorten this to:

```
if id "$line" &> /dev/null    # Find out if the user exists, without printing anything
then
    echo "$line"              # The user exists (`id` succeeded)
else
    echo "$line is not valid user ID" >&2     # No such user
fi
```

**Edit 2** If you don't need the `not valid` output, you can replace the whole `if`..`fi` block with

```
id "$line" &> /dev/null && echo "$line"
```

If the command before `&&` succeeds, bash runs the command after `&&`.

Comment: awesome, you rock. I'll mark this answered in a minute, and thank you for your help and elegant solution. Cheers

Comment: @Dan Glad to help!  I'm going to delete my comments just to clean things up.